# JMeter logging of every http request and response and details report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to do load test a website and want to send 10k request in 1 min. How can I log every request and their responses to create a detailed report.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1. Use JMeter's built-in functionality to store the request/response details into .jtl results file, adding the next lines to *user.properties* file will change the way JMeter stores metrics:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   ```

   More information: [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

   Be informed that you won't be able to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from .jtl files in XML format
2. Use a separate [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) to store the metrics you're interested in into a separate file, a good candidate is Simple Data Writer:
   a
   [image]

   More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: does solution #1 have to output in XML format?  Would the solution work if that first line were omitted?